# 'length' is null or not an object? IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I get the following error in IE8:

> length is null or not an object

Anyone have any ideas? Feedback greatly appreciated.

```
function refresh() {
  $.getJSON(files+"handler.php?action=view&load=update&time="+lastTimeInterval+"&username="+username+"&topic_id="+topic_id+"&t=" + (new Date()), function(json) {
    if(json.length) {
      for(i=0; i < json.length; i++) {
        $('#list').prepend(prepare(json[i]));
        $('#list-' + count).fadeIn(1500);
      }
      var j = i-1;
      lastTimeInterval = json[j].timestamp;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Make sure your JSON is properly formatted. "Property":"Value" the quotes are necessary.

Also, what doctype are you using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just check for the object being null or empty:

```
if (json && json.length) {
  // ...
}
```

C'mon gang this was glaringly obvious :-)

Comment: lol I think that may have fixed it, I will check back in a little bit after some testing

Comment: ps I like your picture, classic painting

Comment: @OK great!  Yes it's an amazing painting, though I feel a little sorry for the poor girl. I always imagine her weeping while her slob of a dad yells,"You're marrying Mr Arnolfini, and **that** is **that**!"

Comment: lol, I suppose that was a reality in those times. I am pretty sure the error is gone lol. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

JSON objects (returned by jQuery or otherwise) do not have a `length` property. You'll need to iterate over the properties, most likely, or know the structure and simply pull out what you want:

```
$.getJSON( ..., ..., function( json ) {
  for( var prop in json ) {
    if( !json.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) { return; }
    alert( prop + " : " + json[prop] );
  }
} );
```

Alternatively, grab a library like [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) and you'll be able to stringify the object for output/debugging.

Answer (score 1):

pop the JSON in a span then clip it and paste it here so we can see it:

```
<span id="JSObject2">empty</span>
```

with the json2.js from here: (link for it at bottom of the page) http://www.json.org/js.html

```
myJSON = JSON.stringify(json);
$('#JSObject2').text(myJSON);
```

Using that, we can help you better, and you can see what you have!

Comment: thanks for that mark, at the start, there is nothing because the function is designed to only return new information on a settimeout period. When information is sent, it looks like this for example [{"timestamp":"1279573958","user":"dfgdfgd","message":"t","creator":""}]

Comment: Thus, there is no length. But, if you do alert(json[0].timestamp); you should see 1279573958 in the alert box.

Comment: yeah I knew there was no length, but it was somehow defined everytime except ofcourse on load when it would not be so I figured it was a javascript standard variable or something lol

Answer (score 0):

A JSON is an object, you seem to be treating it like an array. Does it really have a `length` property? Show us the JSON?

You might need to use a `for..in` instead.

EDIT: Can you make the JSON from the backend structure like so?

```
({
    "foo": [] 
})
```

Comment: it just says [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],

Comment: when I use alert(json); after if(json.length) {

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean from making the json from the backend structure. I am gathering the information from a php document which gets the information from the database and puts it into a json array like so $data[] = $row;  $out = json_encode($data);
  print $out;

Comment: Why can't you just show us that real JSON? Or mimic it exactly.

Comment: I did lol see the comment I made to Mark Schultheiss, after he showed me how to actually show the raw json, since it was getjson function, I did not know how to show the json but he showed me

Comment: Uh. Just go to your JSON page directly...And download it or whatever. You don't need to do it in JS.

Comment: lol there were too many undefined variables and complications, since I was retrieving information not posting it and retrieving, (it was not a form posting), which yes, I do admit that would have been easy. Mark had the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

What does your returned JSON look like?  If you're returning an object, length might not be explicitly defined, whereas if you're returning an array, it should be defined automatically.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is that length is not a property of whatever json is. What is the json variable supposed to be anyway?